# Processing multi line log entry into a single line

Tags: logging, awk

I have been adding XML tags to proxy error logs using the awk command

```
awk ‘{ print “<record><data name=\”F1\” <value>=\””$1”\”/><data name=\”F2\” <value>=\””$2”\”/><data name=\”F3\” <value>=\””$3”\”/>; for ( i=4; i<=NF; i++ ) {printf “%s “, $i}; print (“\””); printf (“\n”) }’
```

each log entry is made up of "TIMESTAMP" "LOG PRIORITY" "UID" "MESSAGE"
and is rotated every 5 minutes, this code is run against the rotated logs.

Today I started getting multi line log entries that will need to be converted into single line entries in the format

```
[16/Mar/2015:10:34:12] Security(29264):
        [CLIENT4330] HTTP5094: while trying to get attribute “user”
        [CLIENT4330] HTTP5094: while trying to get attribute “invalid-password”
        [CLIENT4330] HTTP5094: ldap password check: LDAP error:
[16/Mar/2015:10:34:12] <Next Log entry>
[16/Mar/2015:10:34:12] <Next Log entry>
```

I have been trying to work out how to capture the multiline log entry and join them into a single line entry appended to the timestamp. 
The indent is 8 spaces.

This code is run on a Solaris 10 instance where I cannot add any other software or modules other than the default install.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This convert all log back to single line if line is not starting with `[`

```
awk '{printf "%s",(/^\[/?RS $0:$0)}' file

[16/Mar/2015:10:34:12] Security(29264):        [CLIENT4330] HTTP5094: while trying to get attribute .user.        [CLIENT4330] HTTP5094: while trying to get attribute .invalid-password.        [CLIENT4330] HTTP5094: ldap password check: LDAP error:
[16/Mar/2015:10:34:12] <Next Log entry>
[16/Mar/2015:10:34:12] <Next Log entry>
```

If you like to get rid of first blank line and get a new line at end, use this:

```
awk '{printf "%s",(/^\[/ && NR>1?RS $0:$0)} END {print ""}' t
[16/Mar/2015:10:34:12] Security(29264):        [CLIENT4330] HTTP5094: while trying to get attribute .user.        [CLIENT4330] HTTP5094: while trying to get attribute .invalid-password.        [CLIENT4330] HTTP5094: ldap password check: LDAP error:
[16/Mar/2015:10:34:12] <Next Log entry>
[16/Mar/2015:10:34:12] <Next Log entry>
```

Extra space can also be trimmed away if needed.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't make it work with my existing awk script as it messes up the tagging, so I set it up as a prefilter and it works perfectly.